# Populating JSON array to drop down reserved word column name conflict

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This is the first time ill use JSON. I used the `json_encode(myarrayhere)` to return array value as shown below.
There is a corresponding value on change of selected value on dropdown.

I verified that I get the array data by using `alert(dataArray)` and it returns like this

```
[{"title":"First"},
 {"title":"Second"},
 {"title":"Third"} ]
```

I used the word **title** as column name for a table I'm using in my database.
But the problem now is how to properly populate them in a drop down. I tried to do `value.title` but it looks like that title is a reserved word/method in php

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {ctgy: selected},    
    url: 'awts.php'  ,         
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (dataArray) {
    alert(dataArray);

    var items = '';
        $.each(result,function(name,value) {
        items += "<option value='"+value.title+"'>"+value.title)+"</option>";
        });
        $("#dropdownselectid").html(items);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `result` is not defined. Substitute `dataArray` for `result` at `$.each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you check the console you'll see that you have a syntax error. You have an extra `)` when you append `value.title` to the HTML string.

Secondly, your `$.each()` call is attempting to loop through `result` when your data is in a variable named `dataArray`.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { ctgy: selected },    
    url: 'awts.php',         
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(dataArray) {
        var items = '';
        $.each(dataArray, function(name, value) {
            items += '<option value="' + value.title + '">' + value.title + '</option>';
        });
        $("#dropdownselectid").html(items);
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4raj6qmz/)

Comment: The issue is `result` is not defined.

Comment: @guest271314 hah! thanks. I put it in the description of the problem, but forgot to change it in code XD